# Kerberos Protocol Centralized Server

Tags: server, protocols, configuration, kerberos

If a small company is expanding with various branches across the country, how would the ***kerberos centralized server*** be configured? Are the new users assigned new ticket granting servers or are they assigned to the already existing ones?